# Derive the distribution of $X=min\{i:S_i=S_{2n}\}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $n\in \mathbb N$ and $X_1,\dots,X_{2n}$ independent and uniform distributed on $\{-1,1\},S_i=\sum_{j=1}^i X_j$ Derive the distribution of $X=min\{i:S_i=S_{2n}\}$.

Clearly $S_i$ should be binomial distributed, Then I tried to solve this problem with a combinatorical argument, but could not conclude anything. How should we tackle this problem?

Comment: By the time reversal, it has the same law as $2n-L$ where $L = \max\{i : 0 \leq i \leq 2n \text{ and } S_i = 0 \}$ is the last visit to the origin. Its law is well-known in the name of *random walk arcsine law*. You may read Section 16.8 of [this](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2016-17/2term/ma003/Notes/Lecture16.pdf) for instance, or just google it.

Comment: @SangchulLee So X's distribution should be $\frac12 -\frac{2}{\pi} arcsin(\sqrt x)$ or?

Comment: No, that is for Brownian motion (which appears as the parabolic scaling limit of a random walk). In this case, we have $$\mathbb{P}[L = 2k] = \mathbb{P}[S_{2k}=0]\mathbb{P}[S_{2n-2k}=0]. $$